# live terminal output with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get back the output of commands using Python.
I already know that subprocess and os modules can do that, but they have one problem.
When i try to run something like Micro or Htop (because i'm on Linux) it just doesn't work.

Basically, i just wanna know how to capture what's on the terminal every second and just `print` it to the screen.

And i'm planning to send the data over the Internet too. So, just capturing the data is easier for me to mess around with

So, any ideas?

Comment: `I am trying to get back the output of commands using Python`.  Are those commands ran with Python subprocess library?

Comment: @LinuxGeek Yes. I just need the commands ran by the Python script.